# System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

This kind of question has been asked several times, and I understand why it happens, and probably nothing we can do about it except retry.

I do have one question on name resolution though.

I am using AWS .Net SDK for 3.5 .Net. I am uploading a big file (>500MB up to 1.5GB, medical images). I call `TransferUtility.Upload()` method.

For most part the program works great.

Occasionally we get this error in the middle of the upload. Usually happens when the internet is slow.

I can catch the exception and retry, which means rery from the beginning since exception happens inside the AWS code.

My question is, if the program has resolved the s3 bucket name and has been uploading for a while why would it give me name resolution error instead of just using the cached resolved name?

Does each thread resolve the name independently and one of thread is failing since the network is saturated? Is this a computer setting? This error we were able to reproduce pretty consistently on a Windows 10 machine with Charter as ISP uploading a 800MB file.

The error occurred after about 250MB upload was done.

This is the actual exception

```
Exception during upload :Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: 
A WebException with status NameResolutionFailure was thrown. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

This web exception is telling you the there was an issue with the "Name Resolution". What it doesn't tell you is that the "name" it's referring to is the "EndpointRegion", for example: USEast1, USEast2 etc.

When using the `Amazon.S3.Transfer.Transferutility` it's crucial that the EndpointRegion you use in the `Upload` call MATCHES that of the bucket you're uploading into.

In my case using `RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("USEast1")` vs `RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("US-East-1")` was the difference maker.

Comment: hum, I have to look into this. I have not had this exception in a while now. I wil lpay close attention to this now. If I recall, I was getting the exception in the middle of a transfer, so it transfers some portion of the file and then gives error.  Appreciate your answer here.

Comment: Not a problem. If it works out for you, would appreciate the upvote/marked-as-correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for this issue could be DNS resolution. If your system is not able to perform DNS resolves it will give you this same error.